# construct a path between $(-1,0)$ and $(0,2)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, connectedness

So we are given a region $S$ which is above the $x$-axis and between the semicircle of radius $1$ and $2$ centered at the origin. We are asked to construct a path that connect the point $(-1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ and then use this concept to show that $S$ is path connected.

I have found a parabola using the point $(-1,0), (1,0)$ and $(0,2)$ but I'm not sure if this parabola stays in the region $S$, and our professor says that an ellipse is a good choice but too fancy for this question...

Is there any simpler curve or line that can be constructed to connect these two points? and how should I use these points to show that $S$ is path connected ?

Comment: or maybe I can use two pieces of straight lines to connect them?

Comment: A path is a continuous mapping from (-1,0) to (0,2), so all you have to do is to connect them without lifting your pen and without going outside of $S$. Two pieces of straight lines would do, yes. Or you can move along the border of the inner circle and then move upwords when you are below (0,2) or diagonally upwords when you are say at $(-ε, 1)$ towards $(0,2)$. In that way (moving along the border of the inner circle and then towards the point) you can connect any two points in S.

Answer (score 2):

From $(-1,0)$, draw a line straigt up, and from $(0,2)$, draw the line to $(-2,0)$. These two lines intersect, and now you should see what path you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your parabola must be $y=2(1-x^2)$. Does it lie inside $S$ ?

As long as $-1\le x\le1$, $y\ge0$, so it stays above the $x$ axis.

Now the squared distance from the origin to a point on the parabola is $d^2=x^2+y^2=x^2+4-8x^2+4x^4=4x^4-7x^2+4$.

Finding the roots of the derivative,
$$16x^3-14x=0,$$
we have $x=0\lor x^2=\frac78$ (one maximum and two minima).

Then when $x^2=\frac78$, $d^2=\frac{15}{16}<1$, and the parabola enters the inner circle.

Actually you can guess that because the inner circle has vertical tangents at $x=\pm1$, unlike the parabola.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following always works for points $A,B$ in your annulus (it's adjusted from Michael's attempt that failed because he used the wrong points.:
The perpendicular bisector of $AB$ intersects one of the line segments $OA$, $OB$ in a point $P$. The circle around $P$ through $A$ also passes through $B$. One of the two arcs is completely within the annulus (why?)